# Apache Commons MultiMap is deprecated, what should I use now?

Tags: java, collections, deprecated, apache-commons-collection

Apache Commons' `MultiMap` interface with its `MultiValueMap` implementation is deprecated since version 4.1. And `MultiHashMap` seems to go entirely...

What should I use as an alternative?

Comment: Just use a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. With the new `Map` methods added in Java 8 these multivalued map type things are unnecessary.

Comment: I used List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>  but someone told me to use MultiHashMap or its replacement for optimization. So i am confused.

Comment: `List<Map<...>>` is definitely not the same as any of the things you mention. They are `Map<K, Collection<V>>`.

Comment: So you mean MultiValuedMap won't work the same way for List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>

Comment: Of course not - it's a multi *valued* map; it supports multiple values per key. Multiple independent maps is completely different. In your use case they may serve the same purpose, but they are definitely not the same thing.

Comment: Those classes are not part of Java itself, so they are not deprecated with any version of Java. You should specify the full qualified name of these class so we know which library they're from.

Comment: How can I check when you don't specify what classes (from which library) you are talking about? There are no classes with these names in the Java SE API, so they are not deprecated in any Java version (given they are not part of Java at all). They may be deprecated in some library, but given you give us no identifying information, we can not be sure which library.

Answer (score 10):

[MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) is the replacement and it isn't deprecated:

> Defines a map that holds a collection of values against each key.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();
>  map.put(key, "A");
>  map.put(key, "B");
>  map.put(key, "C");
>  Collection<String> coll = map.get(key);
> ```

It replaced [MultiHashMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html)

> Class now available as MultiValueMap in map subpackage. This version is due to be removed in collections v4.0.

and [MultiValueMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html):

> **Deprecated.** 
>   since 4.1, use MultiValuedMap instead

The deprecation related to apache commons collections4 dependency jar

I think the third you meant `MultiMap` was deprecated

Comment: (MultiValuedMap cannot be resolved to a type) is the error i am getting.

Comment: @WhiteWalker you can use `MultiValuedMap<String, String> map = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();`

Comment: But what i have to import because its giving error as mentioned in MultiValuedMap and ArrayListValuedHashMap cannot be resolved.

Comment: @WhiteWalker the commons-collections4 jar: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0